# Asp.net Mvc Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

Ok

I have the following view structure:

```
Views/Level1/Level2/View.aspx
Views/Level1/Level2/DisplayTemplates/MyDisplayTemplate.ascx
```

for this to work, inside my action I have to do this:

```
return View("Areas/Area1/Views/Level1/Level2/View.aspx", model);
```

All good in the hood...

Except. The display templates are obviously lost or something? I have UiHint on the model and i tried calling

```
Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Property, "PathToDisplayTemplate")
```

too but nothing seems to want to make it do its thang :(

any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Read comments also ...

Wouldn't you just have:

```
Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Property, "MyDisplayTemplate")
```

This will then look for a `DisplayTemplates` folder in the same folder as the view and look for `MyDisplayTemplate.ascx` inside there.

---

Also if you have this exactly: `return View("Areas/Area1/Views/Level1/Level2/View.aspx", model);`
there might be something wrong, i can't think why you would need to be so explicit.

MVC will look for a view in the folder for that controller (For example; HomeController, there will be a Folder called "Home" in views)

It will then look to match the name of your action to the name of the view within that folder.
For example if you have public ActionResult Index() it will look in Views/Home/Index.aspx

meaning you only need to write "return View()" or "return View(model)" if you are passing in a model.

Hope i haven't misunderstood your requirements and telling you something you already know,

Regards, Kohan.

Comment: this is what i thought - in fact - the UiHint on the property should mean i dont even have to specify the MyDisplayName in the DisplayFor? On your second point: the view folder has a sub view folder - so the controller gets confused. I think this combined with the area setup is confusing the sh*t out of it :(

Comment: Okay, out of curiosity Why do you have it in a subfolder?

Comment: i'm going to do some juggling. i wanted to follow the natural flow the app dictates, kinda resent having to do this because of the limitations of the FW :s

Comment: I don't know if it helps in your case but there's also the Shared folders if you need content in more than one place.

Comment: i had to shuffle everything about so it's in a flat structure. not happy wiht that but there we go. marking this one correct - so long as people read all the comments should be ok :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience one wouldn't program a partial view in the controller but would instead use a normal view and then handle the partials in that view or in it's viewmodel, I'll try and see how to do it ur way but heres at least how I do it.

Edit-
oh yeh

```
return View("Areas/Area1/Views/Level1/Level2/View.aspx", model);
```

would return a normal view but since ur asking for a display temp then that should be a ascx so it could just be that which is the issue.

Comment: View.aspx uses the MyDisplayTemplate by calling Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Property) - the Property on on the model has the UiHint of MyDisplayTemplate which should point it to iews/Level1/Level2/DisplayTemplates/MyDisplayTemplate.ascx